# Continuously Differentiable in $\mathbb{R^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

I understand the concept of continously differentiable (first derivative is continuous) in $\mathbb{R}$, however what does it mean for the RHS of:

$\dfrac{d}{dt} \begin{pmatrix}u\\v\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos u+v^2\\u-\sin v\end{pmatrix}$

to be continously differentiable? Does it have something to do with the Jacobian?

Comment: It means, every entry of the Jacobian is continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the partial derivatives exist and are continuous.